# Como reportar erros na tradução?

Tags: suporte, tradução

Qual o caminho para reportar bugs de tradução do site?

Exemplo, no tour do site encontrei alguns trechinhos com tradução faltando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Também encontrei problemas ao dar um ponto negativo à uma resposta: "Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved"

Comment: Boa. É, talvez dê pra reportar aqui no meta, mesmo. =)

Comment: Acho que o lugar é aqui mesmo!

Comment: Na seção **Reputação** do resumo do perfil do usuário (http://br.stackoverflow.com/users/256/paulo-morgado) tem o seguinte texto: "Você não tem _positive_ alterações da reputação recentes"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O melhor jeito de reportar é pelo Meta mesmo. As tags vão ser [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) e [traducão](/questions/tagged/traduc%c3%a3o).

Dá uma olhada [nesse post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10/sobre-partes-do-site-em-ingles), ele tem o processo que nós vamos adotar por enquanto pros erros de tradução.

Comment: Beleza, valeu, Gabe!