# Sobre partes do site em inglês

Tags: debate, tradução

Nós sabemos que algumas boas partes do site ainda estão em inglês. Traduzir um site desse tamanho é uma tarefa incrivelmente longa, e nós ainda estamos trabalhando nisso.

Vocês já repararam que algumas coisas não foram traduzidas ainda... Isso é porque o trabalho ainda não chegou lá. Nós sabemos disso e toda semana novas partes vão sendo traduzida. A idéia é que o lançamento oficial ocorra com tudo 100% traduzido, mas para o beta privado um site "bilingue" é o esperado. Nós acreditamos que tudo que é essencial para o funcionamento do site já está traduzido, mas se você acredita que alguma parte precisa ser priorizada, pode botar no meta.

Quanto a erros na tradução, vale o mesmo procedimento de avisar no Meta. 100 pessoas são muito mais capazes de chegar numa proposta melhor de tradução do que qualquer pessoa sozinha.

## Como reportar um problema de tradução

O melhor lugar é usar o nosso digníssimo Meta. Se você encontrou um erro ou algo que nao foi traduzido, crie um novo post no Meta mostrando **onde exatamente é o problema** (se possível com screenshot), seguindo uma das seguintes opções:

- **Se for uma parte do site ainda em inglês:** Use as tags [bug](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) e [internacionalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internacionaliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o)
- **Se for um erro ou melhoria em algo já em português:** Use as tags [bug](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) e [localização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

A separação dessas tags permite que a gente possa entender e separar melhor o que ainda precisa ser feito,

Se você já tiver uma proposta de melhoria, **adicione como reposta** (de novo, se possível com um mockup). Caso você ainda não tenha uma solução, dê uma sugestão do que você pensa a respeito no post, e fique de olho nas respostas, para votar na que você mais gostar.

Eu sei que pedir screenshot parece um trabalho desnecessário, mas lembrem-se que os devs não falam português, então qualquer forma de ajudá-los a entender exatamente o que a gente quer é muito bem vinda. Usem os círculos do Freehand ;)

Criar um post pra cada problema é um bom jeito de gerenciar o que está sendo feito, descobrir se o problema já foi reportado e controlar o que ainda precisa ser feito. Manter todas as sugestões em respostas serve para a comunidade poder votar no que eles consideram a solução ideal.

## E depois?

Toda sexta feira eu vou ver a lista dos problemas mais votados, e as melhores soluções, editar as tags pra indicar que eles foram aceitos e mandar para os devs.

É um processo mais trabalhoso do que o normal, mas evita alguns gargalos e distribui o trabalho de corrigir as traduções, pra todo mundo poder ajudar.

**Eu não recomendo reportar páginas que ainda estão em inglês.** Se ainda não foi traduzido é porque o processo de localização ainda não chegou lá, e propor uma tradução agora mais atrapalha que ajuda.

Comment: Fala aí, Gabe! Além de avisar, tem mais alguma coisa que podemos fazer para ajudar na tradução?

Comment: @elias Caso você tenha uma solução proposta, só mandar junto no post

Comment: Bem, gostaria de "reportar" um problema de tradução neste post: A palavra "reportar" é um anglicismo, não é uma palavra típica da língua portuguesa. O ideal é usar "relatar".

Comment: @Victor Não há exigência de que todo mundo no site tenha que falar o português mais puro possível. Especialmente na nossa área, existem diversos anglicismos, neologismos ou termos puramente em inglês que são naturais e não tem nenhum problema em utilizar.

Comment: +1 Pelos "círculos do freehand". ;) http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775

Answer (score 20):

Sinceramente não entendi essa decisão da equipe de terceirizar a tradução, ainda mais com tantos usuários demonstrando, há meses, disposição para colaborar com o processo, de graça. O resultado mostra muito do que eu já esperava: diversas traduções literais e/ou fora do contexto, coisa comum em traduções de software feitas por quem não tem experiência no uso da ferramenta que está traduzindo.

Tudo bem, não adianta chorar sobre o leite derramado. Eu pessoalmente continuo disposto a colaborar revisando traduções, completando-as e sugerindo alternativas. Porém, tem uma coisa que me deixa com o pé atrás de mergulhar nisso: **não sabemos em que vocês já estão trabalhando**. Não quero duplicar trabalho que já esteja sendo feito. Por exemplo, tem várias coisas em inglês na página do tour. Pensei em postar aqui no meta uma nova versão dessa página, mas vai que 15 minutos depois de eu postar vocês atualizam essa página com uma versão diferente da que usei como base?

Então pergunto: seria possível organizarmos um pouco melhor esse processo, de modo a dividir as tarefas e evitar desperdício de tempo e esforço?

Comment: Nem todos os usuários vão ter acesso a todas as páginas do site, nem tudo que precisa ser traduzido é diretamente visível na interface. Traduzir um bloco grande de texto "por comitê" demora mais do que uma pessoa traduzir e várias revisarem... Não havia nenhuma forma hábil e passar o trabalho de localização para a comunidade. Os problemas iam acontecer, com certeza, mas era o melhor caminho.

Comment: Pela forma que o SE funciona, eu "tinha certeza" que seria disponibilizado uma ferramenta para a comunidade traduzir o site. Nunca achei que diria isso... Saudades do Jeff :) Mas paciência, quem não tem cão caça com gato.

Comment: @Gabe Especificamente sobre aquela página do tour, você considera "traduzida" e portanto passível de revisão? Ela está semi-traduzida. A primeira frase, por exemplo, é "Stack Overflow em Português é um site de perguntas e respostas para *professional and enthusiast programmers*." (grifos meus)

Comment: @bfavaretto Ela foi (mal) traduzida e é passível de correção. Tudo que tiver pelo menos alguma coisa em português pode ser corrigido. Se tiver 100% em inglês, melhor esperar.

Comment: @Gabe Mas não é um bloco grande de texto, são vários pequenos blocos de texto. Na minha opinião, tradução "por comitê" seria ideal nesse caso.