# Problema com as traduções da seção de "votos"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização

O menu "votos" que mostra toda a atividade de votação do usuário está com traduções inadequadas para o português, conforme mostra o screenshot em anexo (traduções circuladas em vermelho).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: I'm on it but will need a lot of work, since we have to add declension rules for each specific tab (currently the sub-tab titles are all rendered in the tab layout/master based on an enum and are the same for all tabs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added overrides for the first 3 items:

```
todas         ==> todos
votar a favor ==> a favor
votar contra  ==> contra
```

Rolling out with build rev `2014.3.13.1452`.

Comment: Don't you think "conclusão" would also sound better as "fechamento"? In portuguese "conclusão" is closer to "conclusion" than "closing".

Comment: @Claudio I don't speak Portuguese (except via google translate, which thinks _fechamento_ means _shutdown_), so both look kind of the same to me...

Comment: Ok, no problem! *fechamento* could be used for *shutdown*, although *desligar* is a better translation (for shutdown). I think *fechamento* is better then *conclusion* because the verb *fechar* is the exact opposite of *abrir*, then if we have *reabrir* meaning *reopen* then voting to *close* would be vote to *fechar*, hence *fechamento* (closure). If you find someone there who speaks portuguese (@Gabe I guess?) you can confirm that.

Comment: Anyway, I find *conclusão* a little awkward for meaning *to close* because, although it can mean *to finish* something - like *conclusão do processo* means *finishing the process* - the word *conclusão* most of the time is used to "thinking something over", like reaching an understanding or summarizing some subject (I guess it is really the same of "conclusion" in english, instead of "closing").

Comment: @Claudio [google translate agrees](http://translate.google.com/#auto/pt/closed%20question)

Answer (score 3):

Seguindo as orientações [deste post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10/sobre-partes-do-site-em-ingles), seguem minhas sugestões de correção:

- todas ==> todos
- votar a favor ==> votos a favor (ou simplesmente "a favor")
- votar contra ==> votos contra (ou simplesmente "contra")

Acho que os seguintes podem ficar mais naturais em português se colocarmos o "para", mas se o omitirmos acho que a idéia ainda é passada.

- exclusão ==> para excluir
- desfazer exclusão ==> para desfazer exclusão
- conclusão ==> para fechamento? (suponho que isto se refira ao equivalente de "close a question")
- reabrir => para reabrir