# Problema com a tradução do relatório de votos

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização

[Nesta outra questão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1043/problema-com-as-traducoes-da-secao-de-votos) havia sido apontado um problema com as traduções da seção de "votos", o que inclusive já foi corrigido, como consta na resposta. Porém, o relatório dos votos na seção de votos ficou com o texto anterior - "votar a favor" no lugar de "voto a favor", e muito provavelmente "votar contra" no lugar de "voto contra". A imagem em anexo mostra o problema em destaque.

[image: image showing inadequate translations]

Comment: Relacionado: [Erro de tradução: votado contra / votar contra](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131/3117)

Comment: A solução pra essa questão é a mesma de http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131/3117