# Problema com traduções na seção "gratificações"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização

O menu "gratificações" - que mostra toda a atividade do usuário envolvendo gratificações - está com algumas traduções inadequadas para o português, conforme mostra o screenshot em anexo (traduções circuladas em vermelho).
[image: Indicação das traduções com problema]

Comment: I'm on it but will need a lot of work, since we have to add declension rules for each specific tab (currently the sub-tab titles are all rendered in the tab layout/master based on an enum and are the same for all tabs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed following strings on the bounty tab:

```
ativo  ==> ativas
obtido ==> obtidas
```

Rolling out with build rev `2014.3.13.1452`.

Comment: You work is not un-noticed. It is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo as orientações [deste post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10/sobre-partes-do-site-em-ingles), seguem minhas sugestões de correção:

- ativo ==> ativas
- obtido ==> obtidas (ou talvez "conquistadas")