# Parte não traduzida do site (em 404 de pergunta deletada pelo autor)

Tags: bug, internacionalização

Embora [haja um post no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10/sobre-partes-do-site-em-ingl%C3%AAs) falando sobre o processo de tradução, ele tem *mais de três anos*... Então acho que encontrei um trecho que foi esquecido mesmo.

Recentemente estava observando [uma pergunta que foi deletada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/186150/%C3%A9-quase-uma-piada-depois-do-susto), e a página diz assim:

> Esta pergunta foi voluntariamente removida pelo autor.
>
> Here are some similar questions that might be relevant:

O da resto da página está em português.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: De uma olhada na [central de ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help), o que tem de coisa la não traduzida não ta no mapa :P

Comment: Verdade, tem bastante coisa não traduzida ainda. O site deve ir priorizando as páginas mais comuns...

Comment: Não encontrei esse texto na página. Na verdade não lembro de ter visto essa frase alguma vez.

Comment: @bigown Adicionei um print.

Comment: Pra mim não aparece esta página :P

Comment: @bigown Talvez não apareça porque nós temos reputação para ver as perguntas eliminadas

Comment: @ramaral exato.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vks7giUwsPs haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já está no [nosso Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/dashboard/) aguardando um momento propício para subir para o site.

Aproveito para convidar todos a ajudar na tradução. Basta se cadastrar lá e começar procurar o que não foi traduzido, tem ferramentas simples para localizar o que ainda falta traduzir.

Comment: @Kahler pronto.