# Tradução para "more than 2 years ago"

Tags: bug, status-aceito, tradução

Percebi, [visualizando um perfil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/60376), que há strings não internacionalizadas (ou que falta a tradução). Um exemplo é o indicador de inatividade quando o usuário está há mais de dois anos afastado - o texto parece em inglês (Visto more than 2 years ago). Tirei um screenshot para demonstrar como exemplo:

[image: Screenshot mostrando o problema descrito no texto]

Acho que vocês podem corrigir isso, né?

Comment: Creio que isso tenha relação com centenas/dezenas de mensagens de traduções aguardando aprovação no https://pt.traducir.win. Talvez essa esteja na fila... Essas sugestões de tradução ficam pendentes de aprovação e quando aprovadas, resolvem problemas como esse.

Comment: Talvez duplicada de: [Sobre partes do site em inglês](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10/sobre-partes-do-site-em-ingl%c3%aas)

Comment: @CmteCardeal ontem mesmo liberei uma série delas. Tinha um lote de sugestões aguardando, hoje caiu pra 4. Essa da pergunta creio que seja uma que liberei agora, depois do deploy (não é instantâneo) confirmo e atualizo as tags da pergunta.

Comment: @CmteCardeal As suas já aprovei a grande maioria, vai ajudar bastante a comunidade. Grato pelo empenho (também vale para os outros colegas que estão participando).

Comment: Fora de escopo, mas uma coisa quero saber o @NoobSaibot é o mesmo NoobSaibot que legendou o One Piece? Se for tenho eterna dívida de gratidão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**P:** *Acho que vocês podem corrigir isso, né?*

**R:** A comunidade toda pode corrigir a maior parte das *strings* do site, participando do esforço coletivo em https://pt.traducir.win/

Em se tratando do trecho específico do *screenshot* da pergunta, um membro da comunidade já mandou a sugestão de tradução, que foi aprovada e provavelmente o problema será sanado na próxima atualização do sistema.

Após publicada a tradução, atualizamos esta resposta e a tag de status.